# error to install mysql-connector-python and mysql-utilities

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I get errors when trying install mysql-utilities and mysql-connector-python, I'm on a virtual machine with centos 7:

```
 [root@local]# yum install mysql-utilities
Complementos cargados:fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.globo.com
 * epel: mirror.ueb.edu.ec
 * extras: mirror.globo.com
 * updates: mirror.nbtelecom.com.br
Resolviendo dependencias
--> Ejecutando prueba de transacción
---> Paquete mysql-utilities.noarch 0:1.6.5-1.el6 debe ser instalado
--> Procesando dependencias: python(abi) = 2.6 para el paquete: mysql-utilities-1.6.5-1.el6.noarch
--> Procesando dependencias: mysql-connector-python >= 2.0.0 para el paquete: mysql-utilities-1.6.5-1.el6.noarch
--> Ejecutando prueba de transacción
---> Paquete mysql-connector-python.x86_64 0:2.1.6-1.el6 debe ser instalado
--> Procesando dependencias: python(abi) = 2.6 para el paquete: mysql-connector-python-2.1.6-1.el6.x86_64
---> Paquete mysql-utilities.noarch 0:1.6.5-1.el6 debe ser instalado
--> Procesando dependencias: python(abi) = 2.6 para el paquete: mysql-utilities-1.6.5-1.el6.noarch
--> Resolución de dependencias finalizada
Error: Paquete: mysql-connector-python-2.1.6-1.el6.x86_64 (mysql-connectors-community)
           Necesita: python(abi) = 2.6
           Instalado: python-2.7.5-48.el7.x86_64 (@base)
               python(abi) = 2.7
               python(abi) = 2.7
           Instalado: python34-3.4.5-4.el7.x86_64 (@epel)
               python(abi) = 3.4
Error: Paquete: mysql-utilities-1.6.5-1.el6.noarch (mysql-tools-community)
           Necesita: python(abi) = 2.6
           Instalado: python-2.7.5-48.el7.x86_64 (@base)
               python(abi) = 2.7
               python(abi) = 2.7
           Instalado: python34-3.4.5-4.el7.x86_64 (@epel)
               python(abi) = 3.4
 Podría intentar utilizar el comando --skip-broken para sortear el problema
Podría intentar ejecutar: rpm- Va --nofiles --nodigest

[root@local]#yum install mysql-connector-python

Complementos cargados:fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.globo.com
 * epel: mirror.epn.edu.ec
 * extras: mirror.globo.com
 * updates: mirror.nbtelecom.com.br
Resolviendo dependencias
--> Ejecutando prueba de transacción
---> Paquete mysql-connector-python.x86_64 0:2.1.6-1.el6 debe ser instalado
--> Procesando dependencias: python(abi) = 2.6 para el paquete: mysql-connector-python-2.1.6-1.el6.x86_64
--> Resolución de dependencias finalizada
Error: Paquete: mysql-connector-python-2.1.6-1.el6.x86_64 (mysql-connectors-community)
           Necesita: python(abi) = 2.6
           Instalado: python-2.7.5-48.el7.x86_64 (@base)
               python(abi) = 2.7
               python(abi) = 2.7
           Instalado: python34-3.4.5-4.el7.x86_64 (@epel)
               python(abi) = 3.4
 Podría intentar utilizar el comando --skip-broken para sortear el problema
Podría intentar ejecutar: rpm- Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

The answers of line command are in spanish because i have the language in this language.

Any help would be gratefully received

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you need python 2.6 and you have 2.7 installed.

Its strange if you have default repositories...

To install python 2.6 you need to add EPEL.

Here is a post similar to your problem.

https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=29976

hope it helps

Juan